# npm svn-interface node programming- multiple method piping

Tags: javascript, node.js, svn

I'm writing a process using npm svn-interface.

I have a file that I want to:

1. Add to svn
2. Commit to svn (with a message)
3. Update the directory from svn.

   ```
   // check this file into svn
   svn.add(tmp, options, function(){
       // what do I do here?
   });

   options.message = "adding a test version to svn";
   svn.commit(tmp, options, function(){
       // what do I do here?
   });

   svn.update(tmp, options, function(){
       // what do I do here?
   });
   ```

When I run the above, the file gets added, but not committed.

What can I do to make these command play nicely, and in order?

**Update**

OK, I tried the code below, but still, only the first task is run:

```
        // Array to hold async tasks
        var asyncTasks = [];

        asyncTasks.push(function(callback){
            // Call an async function, often a save() to DB
            svn.add(testFile, options, callback);
        });
        asyncTasks.push(function(callback){
            options.message = "adding a test version to svn";
            svn.commit(testFile, options, callback);
        });
        asyncTasks.push(function(callback){
            options.message = "adding a test version to svn";
            svn.update(testFile, options, callback);
        });

        async.parallel(asyncTasks, function(){
            // All tasks are done now
            console.log('finished');

        });
```